# How to upload different photos to localhost

Tags: php, android

I have created following code to upload photos from an android app to localhost with php. But when we are uploading different photos with different names it uploaded same photo that uploaded first with the new name. How can i upload different photos to the local host using different names?Any help will be highly appriciated.

```
package com.androidcodefinder.androiduploadimage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button GetImageFromGalleryButton, UploadImageOnServerButton;

    ImageView ShowSelectedImage;

    EditText imageName;

    Bitmap FixBitmap;

    String ImageTag = "image_tag" ;

    String ImageName = "image_data" ;

    ProgressDialog progressDialog ;

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream ;

    byte[] byteArray ;

    String ConvertImage ;

    String GetImageNameFromEditText;

    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection ;

    URL url;

    OutputStream outputStream;

    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter ;

    int RC ;

    BufferedReader bufferedReader ;

    StringBuilder stringBuilder;

    boolean check = true;

    private int GALLERY = 1, CAMERA = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GetImageFromGalleryButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSelect);

        UploadImageOnServerButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);

        ShowSelectedImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        imageName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.imageName);

        byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        GetImageFromGalleryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                showPictureDialog();


            }
        });


        UploadImageOnServerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                GetImageNameFromEditText = imageName.getText().toString();

                UploadImageToServer();

            }
        });

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        5);
            }
        }
    }

    private void showPictureDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder pictureDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        pictureDialog.setTitle("Select Action");
        String[] pictureDialogItems = {
                "Photo Gallery",
                "Camera" };
        pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                            case 0:
                                choosePhotoFromGallary();
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                takePhotoFromCamera();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
        pictureDialog.show();
    }
    public void choosePhotoFromGallary() {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY);
    }

    private void takePhotoFromCamera() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == this.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
            if (data != null) {
                Uri contentURI = data.getData();
                try {
                    FixBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), contentURI);
                    // String path = saveImage(bitmap);
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ShowSelectedImage.setImageBitmap(FixBitmap);
                    UploadImageOnServerButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
            FixBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ShowSelectedImage.setImageBitmap(FixBitmap);
            UploadImageOnServerButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //  saveImage(thumbnail);
            //Toast.makeText(ShadiRegistrationPart5.this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    public void UploadImageToServer(){

        FixBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, byteArrayOutputStream);

        byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

        ConvertImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

        class AsyncTaskUploadClass extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

                super.onPreExecute();

                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Image is Uploading","Please Wait",false,false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String string1) {

                super.onPostExecute(string1);

                progressDialog.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,string1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

                ImageProcessClass imageProcessClass = new ImageProcessClass();

                HashMap<String,String> HashMapParams = new HashMap<String,String>();

                HashMapParams.put(ImageTag, GetImageNameFromEditText);

                HashMapParams.put(ImageName, ConvertImage);

                String FinalData = imageProcessClass.ImageHttpRequest("http://192.168.137.1/Android%20Upload%20Image/upload-image-to-server.php", HashMapParams);

                return FinalData;
            }
        }
        AsyncTaskUploadClass AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ = new AsyncTaskUploadClass();
        AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ.execute();
    }

    public class ImageProcessClass{

        public String ImageHttpRequest(String requestURL,HashMap<String, String> PData) {

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                url = new URL(requestURL);

                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(20000);

                httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(20000);

                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

                bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(

                        new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

                bufferedWriter.write(bufferedWriterDataFN(PData));

                bufferedWriter.flush();

                bufferedWriter.close();

                outputStream.close();

                RC = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

                if (RC == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));

                    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    String RC2;

                    while ((RC2 = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){

                        stringBuilder.append(RC2);
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }

        private String bufferedWriterDataFN(HashMap<String, String> HashMapParams) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> KEY : HashMapParams.entrySet()) {
                if (check)
                    check = false;
                else
                    stringBuilder.append("&");

                stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(KEY.getKey(), "UTF-8"));

                stringBuilder.append("=");

                stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(KEY.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
            }

            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 5) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Now user should be able to use camera

            }
            else {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unable to use Camera..Please Allow us to use Camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }
}
```